# A solid, real question of mine w/ 18 up votes, 4 stars was removed. And I can't figure out why :-/

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

A solid, real question of mine w/ 18 up votes, 4 stars was removed. I want to know why. It was posted on September 7, 2010 and closed on September 11, 2012, a full two years later.

[Are "elseif" and "else if" completely synonymous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662412/are-elseif-and-else-if-completely-synonymous)

They say it was not a constructive question, but 18 people and myself think it is.  I am a PHP veteran and even I was not sure of the differences.

I want to know why it was closed. They say it's not a "constructive" question. Well, here it is:

> Are `elseif` and `else if` completely synonymous?
>
> Does Zend have an accepted "standard" on which one to use?
>
> I personally greatly dislike seeing `elseif` in the code. Just use `else if` like every other language, right? But I just need to know if they're synonymous and the PHP manual isn't the easiest to search.

The answer received 34 net upvotes.

Here's a mirror: http://www.permamarks.net/grabbed_urls/OQhBYg/webcache.googleusercontent.com_38.htmlz

Comment: Looks like a valid question to me. Voted to undelete.

Comment: I personally found this question useful. I remember looking at it not even a few months ago because I was, myself, curious. I'm surprised to see it deleted.

Comment: Just a note, _"I want"_ scans badly for me. It may not for other people but, to me, it sounds quite confrontational in this context.

Comment: It has now been undeleted.

Comment: Some of the characters involved in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146985/policy-on-reputation-abuse-from-vindictive-redditor-trolls also voted to close that question... hmm...

Comment: "Post Deleted by tereško, Baba, PeeHaa, John Saunders, AVD" Gee, why am I not surprised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only two things I can think of that make this question unconstructive:

1. You added a line in there about your personal preference.
2. Both of your questions could technically be answered with yes or no.

The question has been undeleted. I've also edited it to remove some of the subjectiveness of your opinions, and also made it so the question isn't so yes/no looking. Other than that, this question is legitimate and the answer does an excellent job at explaining it. A lot of people in PHP complain over others using one syntax versus the other (my friend has asked me before why I include spaces, and I just told him it's my preference), and it's nice to have a question and answer that explains that it really doesn't matter.