# Why does deleting require 5 votes and undeleting only 3?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

Consider the revisions for this question, which I looked at following <s>someone crying over lost rep</s> another meta question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155824/).

As far as I can tell, a sum total of 9 people though it bad enough to close/delete, but only 5 were required to replenish its mana.  That's just an observation though.

**The question is** - why does deleting require 5 votes and **un**-deleting only 3?

An answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51272/how-many-votes-are-needed-to-undelete) probably answers the undelete vote count part of this question.  But this question goes a bit deeper, and discusses the seemingly unmatched unique number of persons between delete and undelete.

Is there a better solution to make sure everyone's vote weighs the same as the next StackOverflower's?

Comment: For the uninitiated, what does a dv on a discussion meta question mean? I know what it means for feature requests.

Comment: I can address the mechanics. The question had a high score, and every +20 score (net) a question gets [makes it one vote harder to delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071). The number of undelete votes not matching the number of delete votes [appears to be by design](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools). As for the rationale... not sure (which is why I'm commenting and not answering). I did see a comment, while looking for the above link, about how the system should err on the side of not removing information from the entire world, but it was not said by a team member.

Comment: The number of required delete votes is now capped at 10, though, so it's not impossible to delete bikeshed questions anymore.

Comment: It's a lot harder to find things to reopen. It's easy to close something but I'd imagine that very few question have gone from deleted to opened without a meta question.

Comment: Which question is 'this question'?

Comment: @Rosinante presumably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662412/are-elseif-and-else-if-completely-synonymous

Comment: It's already much harder to delete questions than it is to undelete them, because you need to have a link to them. It makes sense to have more upvoted questions being harder to delete. It doesn't make sense to make them harder to undelete. If anything they should require *less* than three votes to undelete. Note that this applies only to popular questions, most questions require the same three votes to delete and undelete.

Comment: Worth noting that supposedly undelete votes [do indeed scale](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52285/99-bottles-of-beer-vs-3-undelete-votes/52844#52844), albeit at a much lower rate of increase than deletion votes.