# What is the minimum level of rep to complete a non-moderator user's power matrix?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, trusted-user

I was previously under the impression that "[Trusted User](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges)" was the highest level of privilege, meaning a 20K users is in all ways equal to a 500K user.  My misconception was brought to a halt today when [Popular Demand's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155836/is-it-a-level-playing-field#comment447988_155836) on another question pointed me to a [page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) that outlined a sliding scale for delete votes.

Reproduced:

> #### How many times can I vote to delete per day?
>
> At 10k, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An additional vote is granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day at 35k reputation.

It would appear a 35K user has a lot more mana to carry out *something* on this site than a 20K user.  Is there a fuller list of privileges including sliding scales than the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges)?  And what is the absolute minimum rep that would max out privileges on all sliding scales (if there were any other than delete votes).

Comment: Nope, you need more than just rep. You also need flag weight to max out your flags.

Comment: As for the scale, "*to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day at 35k reputation*" .. if you have 300k, you still get 35 votes per day.

Comment: Flags also increase with rep (until the maximum 100 is reached). I'm not sure whether rep can make up for low flag weight entirely, though.

Comment: @Tim I did compare 35K to 20K, not 300K to 35K...

Comment: @DanielFischer Currently I have 70k and maximum flag weight (I was at 750 when they hid it and I've never had a declined flag since). And right now I have 77 flags...

Comment: Related: [At what reputation does a user gain 100% maximum privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136020/at-what-reputation-does-a-user-gain-100-maximum-privileges)

Comment: @Mysticial I'm a bit below 60K and have 71 flags. But my flag weight should also be at least _very_ close to 750 (9 declined out of ~7K flags), so that's just the six full 2K-rep difference.

Comment: Related [What privilege should 30k users get?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252690/289691)